# scrape additional pages of listing data from realtor.com

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I have the code below.  It pulls home listing data from realtor.com using beautiful soup by zip code.  The code below will pull the first 47 listings, but doesn't pull anything on the next page.  For example for the test case below zip code 94016 there are 2000 or so listings.  There's a button at the bottom of the page where I can click 'next'.  I suppose I could try to add some code to click it using selenium.  Does anyone know a slicker way to pull all the listings?

code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) ' \
                                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                                  'Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
}
#'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'

url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/94016'

response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

#print(response.content)

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')


for item in soup.select('.component_property-card'):
    try:
        print('**********')
        #print(item)
        print(item.select('[data-label=pc-price]')[0].get_text())
        print(item.select('img')[0]['data-src'])
        print(item.select('.summary-wrap')[0].get_text())
        print(item.select('.address')[0].get_text())
        print(item.select('.property-meta')[0].get_text())
        print(item.select('.special-feature-list')[0].get_text())
        
        price_list.append(item.select('[data-label=pc-price]')[0].get_text())
        
        
        
    except Exception as e:
        #raise e
        print('')
```

update:

```
# first run
soup_list=[]

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) ' \
                                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                                  'Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
}
#'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'

# url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/San-Francisco_CA'

url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/94016'

response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

#print(response.content)

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

i=2

print(url)

print('lenght: '+str(len(soup.select('.component_property-card')[0])))


print(str(i))




while len(soup.select('.component_property-card'))!=0:

    
    
    
    try:
    
        headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) ' \
                                      'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                                      'Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
    }

        # waits between pulling data
        time.sleep(np.random.randint(low=60, high=70, size=1)[0])

        url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/94016'+'/pg-'+str(i)

        print(url)

        response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

        #print(response.content)

        soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

        print('length: '+str(len(soup.select('.component_property-card')[0])))

        i=i+1

        print(str(i))

        soup_list.append(soup)
        
    except:
        
        headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) ' \
                                      'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                                      'Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
    }

        # waits between pulling data
        time.sleep(np.random.randint(low=60, high=70, size=1)[0])

        url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/94016'+'/pg-'+str(i)

        print(url)

        response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

        #print(response.content)

        soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

        print('length: '+str(len(soup.select('.component_property-card')[0])))

        i=i+1

        print(str(i))

        soup_list.append(soup)
```

update:

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"))


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/94534'

# keep simple and download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (match version of Chrome installed)
# put file in same folder as the script
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
sleep(3)

# dictionary to store page title as key and html scraped as value
pages = {}

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

pages['Page 1'] = soup

for i in range(0, 4):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="srp-body"]/section[1]/div[2]/div/a[8]').click()
    sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    
    
    # DO SOMETHING SMARTER HERE TO FILTER WHAT IS REQUIRED, or just get the whole page...
    # I doubt you want the whole page but for a demo it shows the idea
    
    # the page title has a '|' and the first part before it is 'Page X' so we could use that
    # split the title, remove whitepace and use the first part as the key for the dictionary
    pages[soup.find('title').text.split('|')[0].strip()] = soup
    
driver.close()

print(len(pages), '\n')
print(pages.keys(), '\n\n')
for k, v in pages.items():
    # just as a check print the first (i.e., find rather than find_all) house address for each page
    print(v.find('div', class_ =\
                 'jsx-303111361 address ellipsis srp-page-address srp-address-redesign').text, '\n')
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b50566b8c5f4> in <module>()
     45 
     46 for i in range(0, 4):
---> 47     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="srp-body"]/section[1]/div[2]/div/a[8]').click()
     48     sleep(5)
     49     soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    391             element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    392         """
--> 393         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    394 
    395     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    964         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    965             'using': by,
--> 966             'value': value})['value']
    967 
    968     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    318         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    319         if response:
--> 320             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    321             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    322                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="srp-body"]/section[1]/div[2]/div/a[8]"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this because I get `403` from the site when pinging it.  However, if the code above works for you this should probably work.  Loop the pages.

Obviously uncomment when ready.  As is it runs a ping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) ' \
                                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                                  'Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
}

main_url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/94016/'

pages = ['pg-2', 'pg-3', 'pg-4']

# loop pages
for page in pages:
    
    url = main_url + page
    
    print(url)

    response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    
    print(response.reason)

#     soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

#     for item in soup.select('.component_property-card'):
#         try:
#             print('**********')
#             #print(item)
#             print(item.select('[data-label=pc-price]')[0].get_text())
#             print(item.select('img')[0]['data-src'])
#             print(item.select('.summary-wrap')[0].get_text())
#             print(item.select('.address')[0].get_text())
#             print(item.select('.property-meta')[0].get_text())
#             print(item.select('.special-feature-list')[0].get_text())

#             price_list.append(item.select('[data-label=pc-price]')[0].get_text())



#         except Exception as e:
#             #raise e
#             print('')
    sleep(3)
```

For me:

```
https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/94016/pg-2
Forbidden
https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/94016/pg-3
Forbidden
https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/94016/pg-4
Forbidden
```

For you it may return OK.

Note the site does work for me via a normal browser so the urls are valid...

[image]

---

**Additional:**

Using Selenium we can loop the pages with the [xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html) of `'//*[@id="srp-body"]/section[1]/div[2]/div/a[8]'`...

[image]

...and grab the HTML into a soup object.

**Try:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/94016'

# keep simple and download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (match version of Chrome installed)
# put file in same folder as the script
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
sleep(3)

# dictionary to store page title as key and html scraped as value
pages = {}

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

pages['Page 1'] = soup

for i in range(0, 4):
    # driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="srp-body"]/section[1]/div[2]/div/a[8]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[aria-label^='Go to next page']").click()
    sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    
    
    # DO SOMETHING SMARTER HERE TO FILTER WHAT IS REQUIRED, or just get the whole page...
    # I doubt you want the whole page but for a demo it shows the idea
    
    # the page title has a '|' and the first part before it is 'Page X' so we could use that
    # split the title, remove whitepace and use the first part as the key for the dictionary
    pages[soup.find('title').text.split('|')[0].strip()] = soup
    
driver.close()

print(len(pages), '\n')
print(pages.keys(), '\n\n')
for k, v in pages.items():
    # just as a check print the first (i.e., find rather than find_all) house address for each page
    print(v.find('div', class_ =\
                 'jsx-303111361 address ellipsis srp-page-address srp-address-redesign').text, '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
5 

dict_keys(['Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3', 'Page 4', 'Page 5']) 


316 Hazelwood Ave, San Francisco, CA 94127 

201 Sansome St Unit 801, San Francisco, CA 94104 

360 Guerrero St Apt 219, San Francisco, CA 94103 

87 Maynard St, San Francisco, CA 94112 

1023 Broadway, San Francisco, CA 94133
```

Comment: thank you for getting back to me with this.  I was able to make it work using your suggestion.  I added an update to my post with the working code.  I had to add a delay inbetween each pull of about 60 seconds, which makes it pretty slow.  Do you have any tips to speed it up, like adding selenium code to click the 'next' button an then get the soup code again with beautiful soup?  Or I know for zillow I can use request with the https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm? link passing zipcode and a geo boundary box to get all listings in one shot.  is there something similar?

Comment: If the code works and the only problem is speed just reduce the wait.  60 seconds is going to be too long.  Try a static `sleep(5)` - remember it's a computer grabbing the source, it's not a human reading it ;o).

Comment: the problem is if I reduce it anymore than 60 sec it fails.  I worked my way up from 10 sec to 60 sec.

Comment: @user3476463 I've added a demo of using Selenium.  Hope that answers your query.  There are different ways to do it etc. so it's just an example of the process.  You could use Selenium more or, as in the demo, just use it to control the page and use BS4 to get the HTML source.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me with this, it seems close to working.  I tried it and it's throwing an error finding the xpath.  I added an update to my original post with the code I ran and the latest error.  I tried inspecting the next button in my chrome window, but couldn't figure out how to find the xpath.  could the xpath be different in my chrome browser?  do you see what might be causing the latest error?

Comment: Strange it's working for me on two separate computers and not for you.  I've updated the code with a different option to get the next page on a CSS selector.  Try that.

Comment: thank you, the second suggestion with the css selector worked slick!